# phpinfo() showing blank page on ubuntu18.04

Tags: apache2, php

I installed phppgadmin using this tutorial. [How to Install PostgreSQL and phpPgAdmin on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-postgresql-installation/)

The `index.html` file is showing fine that comes already installed.

But when I made a `php` file to display `phpinfo();`, it shows blank page.

This is the output of `root@pan0xxx:/# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
root@pan0138:/# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Oct 08 00:08:14.178971 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31651:tid 140420410256320] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) con    figured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Oct 08 00:08:14.178994 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31651:tid 140420410256320] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache    2'
```

**EDIT**

Output of `/# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` after installing php separately.

```
root@panxxx:/# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Tue Oct 09 00:06:22.406750 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31651:tid 140420410256320] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configu     red -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 09 00:06:22.406777 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31651:tid 140420410256320] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Oct 09 12:05:47.122881 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31651:tid 140420410256320] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Oct 09 12:05:47.188994 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4685:tid 140256460741568] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configur     ed -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 09 12:05:47.189114 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4685:tid 140256460741568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Is your `php` file just `<?php phpinfo();` or does it contains other commands?

Comment: yes only <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: try to remove your index with type `sudo rm -f /var/www/html/*`and restart your pgadmin, and did you check your email sir?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: I will check sir. Just give me little time. Thank you for prompt !

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: it's not pgadmin, phppgadmin. I tried install using this tutorial: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-postgresql-installation/

Answer (score 2):

What I did is something like this:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.2
```

If you get an error message showing conflicts, such as in my case I had: mpm_event error, you do this:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
```

you'll get messages like "apache2 crashed!" or something. Don't worry. Do the same a2dismod for all errors. Once done, execute:

```
systemctl restart apache2
sudo a2enmod php7.2
systemctl restart apache2
```

And that should do the trick! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me, under Ubuntu 20.04, it was

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That fixed the `phpinfo()` being empty.

Answer (score -1):

Hello U might be not installed php You judt install apache2 server.
In this case apache2 supports html pages but for php you need to install php
For this you may run below command...
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install php7.0*

Comment: From the tutorial I followed, link above, I used this command:
sudo apt -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib phppgadmin
Do you think it will not have installed php ?

Comment: No it will only install following additional packages will be installed:
  postgresql-9.5 postgresql-client-9.5 postgresql-client-common
  postgresql-common postgresql-contrib-9.5 sysstat

Comment: you need to install php seperatly

Comment: I installed and restart the apache but it still shows blank page. The output of  
# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log 
now I added to OP.